# Получение .c и .h файлов при использовании cython

Tags: python, c, cython

Можно ли получить .h и .c файлы при компиляции python кода с использованием cython?

Видел примеры, не могу снова их найти.

Суть такая, мы пишем python функции, потом как-то из файла с функциями на питоне получаем .h и .c файлы, которые используем следующим образом

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "hello.h"

int main(void){
    Py_Initialize();  
    inithello();    
    say_hello();
    Py_Finalize();   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Достаточно объявить функцию с модификатором `public` и будут экспортированы заголовочные файлы.

**hello.pyx**

```
cdef public say_hello():
    print('Hello')
```

Транслируем

```
$ cython hello.pyx
```

**run.c**

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "hello.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Py_Initialize();

    PyInit_hello();
    say_hello();

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Компилируем

```
$ gcc $(python-config --cflags) $(python-config --ldflags) hello.c run.c
```

Почитать об этом можно в [соответствующем разделе документации](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c).