# gcc компиляция файла, полученного с помощью cython

Tags: python, c, gcc, ld, cython

Пытаюсь использовать полученный с помощью `cython` файл `.c` по [данному примеру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/888801/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-c-%D0%B8-h-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-cython/).

**OS - 18.04.1-Ubuntu**

На `cython` код самый простой:

```
# program.pyx

cdef public int test():
    print('hello, world')
    return 0
```

Далее на `bash`:

```
cython program.pyx
```

Получил файлы:

- `program.h`
- `program.c`

Написал дальше файл `.c`:

```
/*--- main.c ---*/

#include "Python.h"
#include "program.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Py_Initialize();

    PyInit_program();
    test();

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Пытаюсь выполнить в bash следующее:

```
gcc $(python3-config --cflags) $(python3-config --ldflags) program.c main.c
```

Получаю ошибки:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cctJoW71.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; перекомпилируйте с параметром -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Раздел, непредставимый для вывода
```

сделал

```
gcc $(python3-config --cflags) $(python3-config --ldflags) -fPIC program.c main.c
```

сыпятся ошибки `undefined reference`

Как это исправить?

---

## UPD. Примеры ошибок

```
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_PrintOne':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1914: undefined reference to `PyTuple_Pack'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_Print':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1872: undefined reference to `PyObject_Call'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1836: undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttr'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_WriteUnraisable':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1506: undefined reference to `_PyThreadState_UncheckedGet'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1513: undefined reference to `PyErr_PrintEx'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1518: undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromString'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1524: undefined reference to `PyErr_WriteUnraisable'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1522: undefined reference to `_Py_NoneStruct'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1522: undefined reference to `PyErr_WriteUnraisable'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_copy_spec_to_module':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1268: undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttrString'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1271: undefined reference to `_Py_NoneStruct'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1272: undefined reference to `PyDict_SetItemString'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1275: undefined reference to `PyExc_AttributeError'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1275: undefined reference to `PyErr_ExceptionMatches'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1276: undefined reference to `PyErr_Clear'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_check_single_interpreter':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1254: undefined reference to `PyThreadState_Get'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1260: undefined reference to `PyExc_ImportError'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1260: undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__pyx_pymod_create':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1288: undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttrString'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1290: undefined reference to `PyModule_NewObject'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1293: undefined reference to `PyModule_GetDict'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__pyx_pymod_exec_program':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1315: undefined reference to `PyExc_RuntimeError'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1315: undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_check_binary_version':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:2457: undefined reference to `PyOS_snprintf'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:2458: undefined reference to `Py_GetVersion'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:2458: undefined reference to `PyOS_snprintf'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:2461: undefined reference to `PyOS_snprintf'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:2465: undefined reference to `PyErr_WarnEx'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__pyx_pymod_exec_program':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1335: undefined reference to `PyTuple_New'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1336: undefined reference to `PyBytes_FromStringAndSize'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1337: undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1375: undefined reference to `PyModule_GetDict'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1377: undefined reference to `PyImport_AddModule'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1379: undefined reference to `PyImport_AddModule'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1381: undefined reference to `PyObject_SetAttrString'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_InitStrings':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:2484: undefined reference to `PyUnicode_InternFromString'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:2486: undefined reference to `PyUnicode_Decode'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:2488: undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:2491: undefined reference to `PyBytes_FromStringAndSize'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:2496: undefined reference to `PyObject_Hash'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__pyx_pymod_exec_program':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1388: undefined reference to `PyObject_SetAttr'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_AddTraceback':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1755: undefined reference to `_PyThreadState_UncheckedGet'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_CLineForTraceback':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1586: undefined reference to `_PyObject_GetDictPtr'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1588: undefined reference to `_PyDict_GetItem_KnownHash'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1569: undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttr'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_CLineForTraceback':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1596: undefined reference to `PyObject_Not'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1596: undefined reference to `_Py_FalseStruct'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1596: undefined reference to `_Py_TrueStruct'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1599: undefined reference to `PyErr_Clear'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1605: undefined reference to `_Py_FalseStruct'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1605: undefined reference to `PyObject_SetAttr'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1607: undefined reference to `_Py_FalseStruct'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1607: undefined reference to `_Py_TrueStruct'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1607: undefined reference to `PyObject_Not'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_CreateCodeObjectForTraceback':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1708: undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromString'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1715: undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromFormat'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1722: undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromString'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1726: undefined reference to `PyCode_New'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__pyx_insert_code_object':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1658: undefined reference to `PyMem_Malloc'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1678: undefined reference to `PyMem_Realloc'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__Pyx_AddTraceback':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1766: undefined reference to `PyFrame_New'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1774: undefined reference to `PyTraceBack_Here'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `__pyx_pymod_exec_program':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1435: undefined reference to `PyErr_Occurred'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1436: undefined reference to `PyExc_ImportError'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1436: undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1392: undefined reference to `PyImport_GetModuleDict'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1393: undefined reference to `PyDict_GetItemString'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1394: undefined reference to `PyDict_SetItemString'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1420: undefined reference to `PyDict_New'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1422: undefined reference to `PyDict_SetItem'
/tmp/ccdRb61X.o: In function `PyInit_program':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/program.c:1242: undefined reference to `PyModuleDef_Init'
/tmp/cc1R5f0v.o: In function `main':
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/main.c:7: undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/cython_to_cpp_trying/main.c:12: undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `перекомпилируйте с параметром -fPIC`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951166/undefined-reference-despite-lib-being-found-by-linker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951166/undefined-reference-despite-lib-being-found-by-linker):

```
gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 p.c -lpython2.7
```

@HolyBlackCat:

> Не знаю, влияет здесь или нет, но `program.c main.c` должно стоять перед флажками линковщика (перед `$(python3-config --ldflags)`)

Comment: Для использования любой версии python также помог коментарий к вопросу от @HolyBlackCat