# gcc ошибка сегментирования при выполнении кода, сгенерированного с помощью cython

Tags: python, c, gcc, segmentation-fault, cython

Пытаюсь использовать полученный с помощью `cython` файл `.c` по [данному примеру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/888801/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-c-%D0%B8-h-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-cython/)

Похожий вопрос задавал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1119239/gcc-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-cython), но по другому поводу

**OS - 18.04.1-Ubuntu**

На `cython` код самый простой:

```
# program.pyx

cdef public int test():
    print('hello, world')
    return 0
```

Далее на `bash`:

```
cython program.pyx
```

Получил файлы:

- program.h
- program.c

Написал дальше файл `.c`:

```
/*--- main.c ---*/

#include "Python.h"
#include "program.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Py_Initialize();

    PyInit_program();
    test();

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Успешно компилирую все с помощью `gcc`:

```
gcc $(python3-config --cflags) program.c main.c $(python3-config --ldflags) -fPIC
```

Компилируется в файл `a.out`, добавил права: `sudo chmod +x a.out`

Однако когда пытаюсь выполнить`./a.out` получаю:

```
Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)
```

**ТАКЖЕ ХОЧУ ЗАМЕТИТЬ**

Если компилировать все с параметрами `python2.7`, `./a.out` успешно выполняется

Для этого в `main.c` поменял строку `PyInit_program();` на `initprogram();` и выполнил:

```
gcc $(python-config --cflags) program.c main.c $(python-config --ldflags) -fPIC
./a.out
```

результат: `hello, world`

Как устранить ошибку для python3?

Answer (score 0):

Задал [вопрос](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3569#event-3297035993) на [исходниках](https://github.com/cython/cython)

Там указали, что `main.c` должен выглядеть так:

```
/*--- main.c ---*/

#include "Python.h"
#include "program.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    PyObject *pmodule;
    wchar_t *program;

    program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        printf("Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0], got %d arguments\n", argc);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (PyImport_AppendInittab("program", PyInit_program) == -1) {
        printf("Error: could not extend in-built modules table\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);

    Py_Initialize();

    pmodule = PyImport_ImportModule("program");
    test();
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Все заработало